# Can ml-engine HP optimization be run locally?

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I am attempting to tune HPs for my model using the ml-engine on a local server. In my case the model trains a single pass, but no HP trials are performed. Is this a configuration issue, or is HP optimization not supported in local mode?

My local command:

> gcloud ml-engine local train --package-path $PWD --module-name example.train --configuration example/hpconfig.yaml -- --param1 16 --param2 2

My config file:

```
trainingInput:
  workerCount: 1
  hyperparameters:
    goal: MINIMIZE
    hyperparameterMetricTag: val_loss
    maxTrials: 10
    maxParallelTrials: 1
    enableTrialEarlyStopping: True
    params:
    - parameterName: param1
      type: INTEGER
      minValue: 4
      maxValue: 128
      scaleType: UNIT_LINEAR_SCALE
    - parameterName: param2
      type: INTEGER
      minValue: 1
      maxValue: 4
      scaleType: UNIT_LINEAR_SCALE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, HP Tuning cannot be run in local mode. I would recommend a workflow like so:

1. Run locally with small data, etc. to ensure everything is working (I recommend using GCS paths).
2. Run a small test on cloud (single job) to ensure dependencies are correct, data files properly point to GCS instead of locally, etc.
3. Run an HP Tuning job.

Once 1 and 2 are working, 3 generally will, too.

Also, as a side note. Kubeflow supports [Katib](https://github.com/kubeflow/katib) for running HP tuning jobs from any kubernetes deployment, including Minikube (for local development).

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Greg consider accepting the answer if it was useful for you.